# Rust : How to get sizeof::<T> in complie time or other way?

Tags: rust, sizeof

I want to convert `T` to bytes array,

```
fn to_byte<T: Sized>(a: T) -> [u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()] {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

when I call this function `let a = to_bytes::<u32>();` the type will be confirmed, but got error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> lab/test-bit/src/main.rs:3:56
    |
3   | fn to_byte<T: Sized>(a: T) -> [u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()] {
    |            - this type parameter needs to be `Sized`   ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
```

Comment: It looks related to https://hackmd.io/aZYPCFBBTyOdKTrqqy4Q3g?view and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76200 .

Answer (score 3):

Stable Rust does not support using generic parameters in const expressions.

In nightly, the code should work as long as you enable `const_generics` and `const_evaluatable_checked`.

In any case, you don't need the `Sized` bound, it is implicit.